# Xcode swift calendar event request between two Firebase users

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, calendar, eventkit

I am currently building a messaging app using Firebase database. I was wondering if it is possible to send calendar event requests between two Firebase users.

So for example, the sender sends an event request to another user, and if the user accepts the request then that event is stored in both the sender and other users calendar.

Is this possible, possibly using eventkit?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is very possible, but completely up to you how you want to implement it.

I would first recommend a firebase function to tackle uploads (below) and then you can very easily send a notification to the other device using the same technique you would for a message.

You uploads could be done any number of ways. I think it is probably best to just mirror the behavior of a messaging app. For example, you have a node/document where you are savings the eventkit data. Upon writing to that node/document, your cloud function is triggered that notifies the receiving device.

I can provide more if necessary, but I would strongly suggest any tutorials about a firebase messaging/chat app but instead of writing a "message/text," you are writing your eventkit data.